# Python Table engine binding for Tokyo Cabinet

Tags: python, tokyo-cabinet

I am looking for python bindings for Table engine of Tokyo cabinet. I tried [Pytc](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytc) but can only find Hash and B-tree engine support. Is there any other bindings available?

Answer (score 7):

Here is an implementation of search of table engine using PyTyrant:

http://github.com/ericflo/pytyrant/tree/master

Comment: Due to my low points here I'm unable to submit links. Swap the hxxp with http to get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

I was in contact with the author of tc and he told me the following:

> Currently, the table (tdb) driver
>   exist in the [master branch](http://github.com/rsms/tc/blob/master/src/TDB.c) ([unit
>   tests](http://github.com/rsms/tc/blob/master/lib/tc/test/tdb.py)) and the [fdb driver](http://github.com/rsms/tc/tree/fdb_rewrite) is
>   being developed in a separate branch.

I tried the table driver for a small test with success, am planning on trying it on larger tables soon.

Answer (score 2):

I've been monitoring (and sometimes improving) various Python bindings for TC for more than a year, so here's an updated list of best bindings matching your criteria.

- For Tokyo Cabinet, including Tyrant: [tokyo-python](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tokyo-python/)
- For Tokyo Tyrant (pure-Python): [pyrant](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyrant/)

There are many stale and/or incomplete alternatives.

Comment: By the way, all recent work is done in my fork of Pyrant: http://bitbucket.org/neithere/pyrant

Answer (score 2):

My branch of pytc called "tc" do have support for tables (TDB) http://github.com/rsms/tc

Basic example:

```
>>> import tc
>>> db = tc.TDB("slab.tdb", tc.TDBOWRITER | tc.TDBOCREAT)
>>> db.put('some key', {'name': 'John Doe', 'age': '45', 'city': u'Internets'})
>>> rec = db.get('some key')
>>> print rec['name']
John Doe
```

Performing queries:

```
>>> import tc
>>> db = tc.TDB("slab.tdb", tc.TDBOWRITER | tc.TDBOCREAT)
>>> db.put('torgny',  {'name': 'Torgny Korv', 'age': '31', 'colors': 'red,blue,green'})
>>> db.put('rosa',    {'name': 'Rosa Flying', 'age': '29', 'colors': 'pink,blue,green'})
>>> db.put('jdoe',    {'name': 'John Doe',    'age': '45', 'colors': 'red,green,orange'})
>>> q = db.query()
>>> q.keys()
['torgny', 'rosa', 'jdoe']
>>> q.filter('age', tc.TDBQCNUMGE, '30')
>>> q.keys()
['torgny', 'jdoe']
>>> q.filter('colors', tc.TDBQCSTROR, 'blue')
>>> q.keys()
['torgny']
>>> # new query:
>>> q = db.query()
>>> q.order('name') # Ascending order by default
>>> q.keys()
['jdoe', 'rosa', 'torgny']
>>> q.order(type=tc.TDBQONUMASC, column='age')
>>> q.keys()
['jdoe', 'torgny', 'rosa']
```

More examples in the TDB unit test: http://github.com/rsms/tc/blob/master/lib/tc/test/tdb.py

Answer (score 1):

The only other one I know of is a fork of pytc but it looks like they have only done some refactoring and documentation work, so probably still only hash and b-tree support:

[tc](http://github.com/rsms/tc/tree/master)

If this doesn't work you are probably out of luck.  I think all the tyrant bindings only use the hash engine.

Comment: I looked at tc and they dont have support for Table either. I think only Perl and Ruby bindings have full support for all bindings.